# cakephp 3.x cascade delete not working

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cascading-deletes

I have 3 tables names articles,comments,addresses.

```
articles -> fields(id,title,body)
comments -> fields(id,article_id,comment)
addresses-> fields(id,article_id,address)
```

and in my articles controller i have kept dependent=>true and also cascadeCallbacks=>true. First i tried with dependent => true,i dint work then added cascade, still it does not work. Below is my code.

```
    $this->hasMany('Comments', [
        'className' => 'Comments',
        'dependent' => true,
        'cascadeCallbacks' => true,
    ]);

    $this->hasOne('Addresses',[
        'dependent' => true,
        'cascadeCallbacks' => true,
    ]);
```

but while deleting articles, associated records are not deleted.

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    $article = $this->Articles->get($id);
    if ($this->Articles->delete($article)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The article has been deleted.'));
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The article could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
    }

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

Please tell me what is the mistake i did. or any code need to be added or changed???? 
Pl help

Comment: what is your exact cake version?

Comment: My cakephp version - 3.3.2

Comment: Are the naming of the files and the namespaces correct? I mean CommentsTable, AddressesTable and so on..

Comment: Yes, I have created the files using bake

Answer (score 5):

Try this :
    `$this->hasMany('Comments', [
        'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
        'dependent'  => true,
        'cascadeCallbacks' => true
    ]);`

Comment: Doesn't work for very deeply associated model.
For example:

`User->Plants->SpecialPlants`

SpecialPlants records do not get deleted.